# Read parameters from Java client in WPF application

Tags: wpf, wcf

I have created WCF service in .net.

It is called by Java client, how do I read parameters when service is being called?

Here is my code:

```
public string getMethod(string id, string name)
{
  string str = name;
  return str;
}
```

Here is my WPF application code, I have added web reference:

```
WebReference.Service1Soap client = new WebReference.Service1Soap();
string str = client.getMethod(id, name);
```

How do I read values of "id" and "name" called from Java client?

I am stuck here, please help me please!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

1. Run a local instance of the service in debug mode, or attach the visual studio debugger to WCF service host process.
2. Put a breakpoint in the getMethod() service operation code
3. Call the service with the java client.
4. Check the values using a watch or just mouseover.

**EDIT**.. from comments...

> but I have set debug point, still it is not happening

That means that your java client call is not being made successfully. If your java client cannot call the service then you need to sort that out first. Please post a new question to address this, or there are plenty of stuff on google: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=problem+calling+wcf+from+java

> I need those parameter values in WPF application and I have to read
>   it. How to do it?

You can't send a message to a service and then have that data relayed to another client (WPF) unless you use callbacks via a duplex binding like `wsDualHttpBinding`, which is not a nice solution in my opinion. More reading here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF

If your java client needs to call into a WPF then you'll need to use `ServiceHost` inside your WPF application and host a WCF service from there. Look here for an example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2013/11/01/wcf-service-hosting-how-to-host-a-wcf-service-from-inside-a-windows-presentation-foundation-application.aspx

**EDIT 2**

> From Java, service client has been made successfully, and it is
>   getting the response. But how do I read parameters, and is there any
>   way or code, that "we come to know that .net service is being called".

Then the only thing you can do is either host the WCF service inside your WPF application, or use a duplex WCF binding on the service, and have the WPF application subscribe by registering a callback delegate. This way the service can call back to the client when something happens (a call is made).

Alternatively you could use a shared database which is updated with the call values when the java client makes the call. Your WPF app can then poll or use a [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to know when the data has changed.

Comment: Thanks brother, but I have set debug point, still it is not happening, and can I store those parameters in variable? @Tom please reply. I need your help

Comment: I need those parameter values in WPF application and I have to read it. How to do it? @Tom

Comment: From Java, service client has been made successfully, and it  is getting the response. But how do I read parameters, and is there any way or code, that "we come to know that .net service is being called". Thanks!!

Comment: @NiteshKothari if this helped you please upvote or make as answer. Thanks